BuildMethodException when trying to build my game
When I'm trying to build my game, I'm getting an error logged to the console:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

What could be the cause of it?
